# Qt, accessing groupBox attribute issues

Tags: python, qt-designer

I've been learning how to use QtDesigner for my course this semester, however I've run into a slight issue with regards to the referencing of attributes within code.

```
class UI (QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self) :
    super(UI,self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('Lab_01_ak07998.ui', self)
    self.show()
    self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateSubcategories)
    #self.authorBox.authorButton.clicked.connect(self.addAuthorToList)
    self.issueBox.issueCheck.stateChanged.connect(self.toggleAuthorFields)
        
def toggleAuthorFields(self,state):
    enable_fields = state == QtCore.Qt.CheckState.Checked
    self.issueBox.issuedBy.setEnabled(enable_fields)
    self.issueBox.issueDate.setEnabled(enable_fields)
```

I'm trying to get the "issueCheck" checkbox to when enabled, also enable the other two fields: issueBy and issueDate. However, these three attributes are within a groupBox by the name issueBox. When I run this code, it's returning an error:

```
AttributeError: 'QGroupBox' object has no attribute 'issueCheck'
```

On QtDesigner, I've already named the objects the exact precise names, I've checked for spaces, saved the doc, restarted the environment but no luck. I can only presume there is some issue with my code or how I'm referencing to attributes stored within a groupBox in my code. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Comment: All the names become attributes of the top-level widget - they aren't nested at all. So simply do e.g. `self.issueCheck.stateChanged.connect(...)`.